# MapR 5.2.2 clients

Tags: go, hbase, mapr

I have a task which requires me to create a Go program to read from an HBASE table.
HBASE is installed in a MapR cluster.
Every other application (Java) uses a MapR client to connect to the MapR cluster so as to retrieve the data.

However, I am unable to find a way to connect to HBASE with a Go application.

I have found HBASE package, but it does not support integration with MapR.

It would be great if anyone could guide me in this situation.

I also have seen that for MapR 6 and above has Go support through OJAI, but sadly, upgrading MapR is not an option.

Can someone advice me how to proceed in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually running HBase in MapR, then the Go package for HBase should work (assuming version match and such).

If you are actually using the MapR DB Binary tables (which are roughly HBase compatible) the likely best approach would be to use the Thrift API or REST.

The OJAI lightweight client should work well in Go since it uses gRPC to talk to the underlying table (and thus gains lots of portability). The problem in your case won't be so much that you need to upgrade the platform so much as the lightweight client only works with MapR DB JSON (the document oriented version of MapR DB).

Ping me directly if you would like more information.